# A question of finding the volume between two curves

Tags: integration

I have a question of finding the volume under the spherical surface

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$$

& over the lemniscate

$$r^2=a^2cos2\theta$$

While solving i know the limits of $z$ are taken from    $0$ to $\sqrt(a^2-x^2-y^2)$
then we find

$$V = \iiint_{z=0}^{ \sqrt(a^2-x^2-y^2)}dxdydz$$

Clearly the region of above double integration is given by projection of the volume on $xy$ plane as follows(in polar form)

[image]

But after then i am little confused for the limits of $r$ & $\theta$.

Can one help me in finding limits and volume .If one give an explanation also it will be so much helpful

Thanks.

Comment: The lemniscate is a 2-dimensional figure and the sphere is 3-dimensional.  I'm confused.  What is the axis of rotation for the lemniscate?

Comment: It seems like a solid ball (sphere) which volume is devided by a plane passing through centre (lemniscate) in 2-D.Is this assumption helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to first realize that one of your equations is in cylindrical while the other in Cartesian. To continue solving the problem you need to change the spherical surface equation to cylindrical so that it should be in the form of $\iiint dzdrd\theta$

So, your spherical surface has a cylindrical equation,

$$z^2=a^2-r^2 \implies z=\sqrt{a^2-r^2} \ \ \ \text{or} \ \  z=-\sqrt{a^2-r^2}$$

You noted that the limits of $z$ start from zero. That is incorrect if you don't consider symmetry. In reality, the limits of $z$ are 
$$\int \int \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} dz dr d\theta$$

We can make use of symmetry and start by zero but multiply by two. This would make integration easier. But, for now I will go about it the normal way. Now, we look at the limits of $r$ and $\theta$ which are,

$$4\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2 \cos(2\theta)}} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} dz dr d\theta=8\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2 \cos(2\theta)}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} dz dr d\theta$$

This assumes we are finding the volume is bounded by the sphere and inside the lemniscate. Your question is unclear in this matter. Note that I multiplied by four because of the symmetry. If $z$ started at zero, we would multiply by $2$ to give $8$.

To find the volume inside the sphere but outside the lemniscate, the $r$ and $z$ limits change. You draw a ray from the center to find the limits of $r$, we want the outside so it meets the lemniscate at $r=a\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ and finishes at $r=a$. The angle is from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So, we have
$$8\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{a\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}}^{a} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} dz dr d\theta$$

Why $8$? For the symmetry on all three axes so $2^3$.

To sum up the solution take a look below the 3D figure of the two surfaces,

[image]

Notice how "over" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dannyobama Please revisit what you have written above. And specifically the order of integration of the triple integral.

Comment: After applying limis of z we will get double integration for which i fig. out the region in whish i have shown eq. of circle in polar form & then i''ll also change integrand in polar form what i'd not write in Q body.but plz understand it & give limits for 'r' & '$\theta$'

Comment: plz clear that if the region is over the lemniscate yet it is symmetrical about z axis How?

Comment: @Dannyobama What do you mean by over the lemniscate?

Comment: over means above

Comment: @Dannyobama You must mean outside the lemniscate but inside the sphere, because over/above the lemniscate doesn't make sense(try to visualize it). I will now add another solution for outside the lemniscate but inside the sphere.

Comment: @Dannyobama Did you understand my answer? Do you want any further clarification? I ask these questions because there meant to highlight if this is an answer you accept. If so, click on the tick(check) next to me answer-when accepted it should turn green. This facilitates other people's work who are searching to answer for questions.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your comment.I understand what you want to say but i am confused that why you extend region of lemniscate in form of a solid in 3-D.while it is only a plane surface having no volume. I visualize it to find a fig. what i stated below the Q-body in my comment @NovaDenizen plz check out that & give resions of mistakes in the solid formed accord me.

Comment: @Dannyobama You must understand that x^2+y^2=4 in 3D is not a circle its a cylinder. Similarly, the lemniscate in 3D is the figure shown above. If we took the lemniscate you suggested it would be a "piece" of  a plane-but that plane is not defined completely by your question. This very plane may even be outside the sphere, may be inside the sphere at an unknown position. The absence of this information and the regularity of the question lead me to believe that your question can't be answered the way you want. My answer is the best possible attempt at the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.you really give me a new way to think about such type of question.I really appreciate you.i was working on this Q & i find two possible ways  to define limits assuming fig. in my way.If you are intrested i think i should discuss method to you & i am incorrect you can correct me.